# Magento2 - Customer group price not reflect after login

Tags: magento2, cart, configurable-product, customer, login

Magento2.1.9 without login when configurable product add to cart, after login with customer not reflecting for customer group price ( tier price) in cart,minicart, checkout section is working fine.